# mySQL query issue -- homework

Tags: mysql

I need some help with one of the questions from my homework, Ive been trying for about an hour now and cant get it to run.

List the customers that bought more items than the average number of items per customer

The tables are as follows:

```
Customer(Cnum, CustomerName, Address)  
Item(Inum, ItemName, Manufacturer, Year)  
Bought(Cnum, Inum, Date, Quantity)   
Prefer(Inum, Cnum)
```

The best i could figure out was that it needs to be the total Quantity per Customer compared to the overall average of the Quantity. I've tried various forms of this query:

```
SELECT Cnum
FROM Bought
WHERE
(
    SELECT Cnum, SUM(Quantity)
    FROM Bought
    GROUP BY Cnum;
) >
(
    SELECT AVG(Quantity)
    FROM Bought
);
```

But it returns an error -- (phpMyAdmin isnt telling me what the problem is, just failing to execute and going to no connection page, which means error in my query)

I have also tried to return the higher SUM with:

```
SELECT SUM(Quantity)
FROM Bought
WHERE SUM(Quantity) > AVG(Quantity);
```

And same issue.

Any help would be appreciated, even an explanation as to why the second one fails.

Comment: there is 2 sums : 4 and 2
and the average is 1.25

so i know which value should show up

Comment: Just a helpful tip: Use MySQL Workbench. It's free and much better at reporting errors

Comment: @nDudani Sorry i didnt think i was going to get to many answers so quickly, i had gone to sleep....I have the answer now thanks to all below, especially JohnFx

Comment: @xbonez thanks for that, i just found Toad for MySQL this morning, but i think ill switch to the workbench ..... so much easier to use too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the [HAVING](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-having.aspx) clause of SQL.

Note: I'm intentionally not giving you the full answer since this is homework.

Comment: from me as well but I can't stop myself to give answer as they try hour or so.

Comment: @JohnFx Thank you. Although I could have easily chosen to just copy a lower answers post, yours got the accepted because it showed me how to fix it, not the fix itself.

Comment: Also  dont remember the teacher showing having, I searched the slides and its on the bottom of one with no examples.

Answer (score 3):

why Don't you try this.

```
SELECT `Cnum` , Sum( Quantity )
FROM `bought`
GROUP BY `Cnum`
HAVING Sum( Quantity ) > ( SELECT AVG( Quantity ) FROM Bought )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this maybe it helps

```
SELECT Cnum, SUM(Quantity) 
FROM Bought
GROUP BY  Cnum
HAVING SUM(OrderQuantity) > avg(Quantity)
```

Comment: Error 1111 - Invalid use of a group function. You can't use aggregates in the WHERE clause.  Change WHERE to HAVING.

Answer (score 1):

Try below:

```
SELECT Cnum
FROM Bought
having SUM(Quantity) > (SELECT avg(Quantity) FROM Bought)
order by SUM(Quantity) desc
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT Cnum, Inum, SUM(Quantity) sum, AVG(QUANTITY) average
from bought group by cnum,inum having sum > average
```